# handle signals in python multi-thread program on freebsd

Tags: python, freebsd, python-multithreading

I write a program by multiprocessing and threading modules in python. I use signals to handle terminating process and threads. it works in Linux, but I have a problem with it on FreeBSD.

I have a main process that create other processes:

```
pr = Process(target=myprocess, args=(queue,))
pr.start()
```

in `myprocess` class I creat a thread:

```
tr = mythread(queue)
tr.start()
tr.join()
```

and use signals to terminate a process and a thread:

```
signal(SIGTERM, terminate)

def terminate(num, frame):
    pr.terminate()
```

for terminate the thread, I write this method in `myprocess` class:

```
signal(SIGTERM, terminate)

def terminate(num, frame):
    tr.terminate()
```

and in `mythread` class I have `terminate` method like this:

```
def terminate():
    exit(0)
```

I read about [sigmask](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/signal.html#signal.pthread_sigmask) in python on Unix and I tested it, but it doesn't work.

my process does not receive `SIGTERM` and it doesn't call `terminate` method of `myprocess` class to terminate the thread.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out that, but I used another way to kill the process.

I wrote process pid  in a file and then use `os.kill(pid, SIGKILL)` to kill the process. And I set thread as a daemon to be terminated when their parent process kills.